# Cant get components to align horizontally with flexDirection in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm mapping over an array to turn a propped state into a number of components.

When I do this, I receive a vertical column of components, not a horizontal one, as you would expect with flexDirection.

This is the styling I have in place:

```
          <View
            sytle={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                flex: 1,
                paddingLeft: 10,
            }}
          >
              { 
                this.props.team.map(
                    (v, i) => {
                        if(v.league.acronym === 'NFL'){
                            return(
                                <Check
                                    checked={ this.props.checkedLeagues.includes(v.league.acronym) ? this.state.checked[i] : false }
                                    index={i}
                                    value={v.team_name}
                                    changeCheck={this.changeCheck}
                                />
                            )
                        }

                    }
                )
             }
          </View>
```

Comment: change the value of  flexDirection to 'column',

Comment: There's a typo in your code. The prop is `style` not `sytle`